# Couldn't initialise audio and illegal state exception

Tags: java, libgdx

I keep getting an error when I run this code.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3 (file:/C:/Users/david/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.3/3df168ac74e4a8c96562cdff24ad352e255bf89c/lwjgl-2.9.3.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$3
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[LwjglApplication] Couldn't initialize audio, disabling audio
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one OpenAL context may be instantiated at any one time.
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:113)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:72)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:71)
    at com.bludbourne.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:20)
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalStateException: From thread Thread[LWJGL Application,5,main]: Thread[LWJGL Application,5,main] already has the context current
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.checkAccess(ContextGL.java:184)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.forceDestroy(ContextGL.java:241)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.destroy(DrawableGL.java:130)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display$5.destroy(Display.java:834)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.destroy(Display.java:1095)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:325)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:250)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:146)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:128)
[MainGameScreen] WorldRenderer: virtual: (10.0,10.0)
[MainGameScreen] WorldRenderer: viewport: (10.0,10.0)
[MainGameScreen] WorldRenderer: physical: (480.0,480.0)
[Utility] Map loaded!: maps/town.tmx
[MapManager] Player Start: (208.0,32.0)
[MainGameScreen] UnitScale value is: 0.0625
```

I don't know what is causing this error or how I can go about solving it. I don't think I have a NullPointerException, however, I don't know. I am not worried about the warnings as they show up on other LibGDX applications that work, so the warnings are not a problem. I am not using any audio files at the moment so I don't know why the error is referring to audio. I don't know what to do so help is much appreciated.

/

```
package com.bludbourne.game.desktop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.bludbourne.game.BludBourne;

public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new BludBourne(), config);


        config.title="BludBourne";
        config.useGL30=false;
        config.width =480;
        config.height=480;

        Application app = new LwjglApplication(new BludBourne(),config);

        Gdx.app=app;
        Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);


    }
}
```

/

```
package com.bludbourne.game.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.bludbourne.game.*;




public class MainGameScreen implements Screen
{

    private static final String TAG=MainGameScreen.class.getSimpleName();

    private static class VIEWPORT{

        static float viewportWidth;
        static float viewportHeight;
        static float virtualWidth;
        static float virtualHeight;
        static float physicalWidth;
        static float physicalHeight;
        static float aspectRatio;
    }

    private PlayerController _controller;
    private TextureRegion _currentPlayerFrame;
    private Sprite _currentPlayerSprite;

    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer _mapRenderer=null;
    private OrthographicCamera _camera =null;
    private static MapManager _mapMgr;

    public MainGameScreen() {

        _mapMgr = new MapManager();
    }


    private static Entity _player;

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        _camera.position.set(_currentPlayerSprite.getX(),_currentPlayerSprite.getY(),0f);
        _camera.update();

        _player.update(delta);
        _currentPlayerFrame = _player.getFrame();
        updatePortalLayerActivation(_player.boundingBox);

        if(!isCollisionWithMapLayer(_player.boundingBox)) {

            _player.setNextPositionToCurrent();

        }

        _controller.update(delta);

        _mapRenderer.setView(_camera);
        _mapRenderer.render();

        _mapRenderer.getBatch().begin();
        _mapRenderer.getBatch().draw(_currentPlayerFrame, _currentPlayerSprite.getX(), _currentPlayerSprite.getY(), 1, 1);
        _mapRenderer.getBatch().end();

    }

    private boolean isCollisionWithMapLayer(Rectangle boundingBox) {

        MapLayer mapCollisionLayer = _mapMgr.getCollisionLayer();

        if (mapCollisionLayer==null) {


            return false;

        }

        Rectangle rectangle =null;

        for(MapObject object: mapCollisionLayer.getObjects()) {

            if(object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {

                rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();

                if (boundingBox.overlaps(rectangle)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }




        }

        return false;
    }


    private boolean updatePortalLayerActivation(Rectangle boundingBox) {

        MapLayer mapPortalLayer = _mapMgr.getPortalLayer();

        if(mapPortalLayer==null) {

            return false;
        }

        Rectangle rectangle=null;

        for(MapObject object:mapPortalLayer.getObjects()) {

            if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {

                rectangle =((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();
                if(boundingBox.overlaps(rectangle)) {

                    String mapName=object.getName();

                    if(mapName==null) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    _mapMgr.setClosestStartPositionFromScaledUnits(_player.getCurrentPosition());
                    _mapMgr.loadMap(mapName);
                    _player.init(_mapMgr.getPlayerStartUnitScaled().x,_mapMgr.getPlayerStartUnitScaled().y);
                    _mapRenderer.setMap(_mapMgr.getCurrentMap());
                    Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Portal Activated");
                    return true;
                }
            }



        }


        return false;

    }



    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        setupViewport(10,10);
        _camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        _camera.setToOrtho(false,VIEWPORT.viewportWidth,VIEWPORT.viewportHeight);

        _mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(_mapMgr.getCurrentMap(),MapManager.UNIT_SCALE);
        _mapRenderer.setView(_camera);


        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "UnitScale value is: "+_mapRenderer.getUnitScale());

        _player = new Entity();
        _player.init(_mapMgr.getPlayerStartUnitScaled().x,_mapMgr.getPlayerStartUnitScaled().y);

        _currentPlayerSprite = _player.getFrameSprite();

        _controller = new PlayerController(_player);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_controller);
    }


    @Override
    public void hide()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public  void resize(int width,int height) {

    }


    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

        _player.dispose();
        _controller.dispose();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
        _mapRenderer.dispose();


    }

    private void setupViewport(int width,int height) {

        VIEWPORT.virtualWidth=width;
        VIEWPORT.virtualHeight=height;

        VIEWPORT.viewportWidth=VIEWPORT.virtualWidth;
        VIEWPORT.viewportHeight=VIEWPORT.virtualHeight;

        VIEWPORT.physicalWidth=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        VIEWPORT.physicalHeight=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        VIEWPORT.aspectRatio=(VIEWPORT.virtualWidth/VIEWPORT.virtualHeight);

        if(VIEWPORT.physicalWidth/VIEWPORT.physicalHeight>=VIEWPORT.aspectRatio) {

            VIEWPORT.viewportWidth=VIEWPORT.viewportHeight*(VIEWPORT.physicalWidth/VIEWPORT.physicalHeight);
            VIEWPORT.viewportHeight=VIEWPORT.virtualHeight;


        }

        else {

            VIEWPORT.viewportWidth=VIEWPORT.virtualWidth;
            VIEWPORT.viewportHeight=VIEWPORT.viewportHeight*(VIEWPORT.physicalHeight/VIEWPORT.physicalWidth);

        }

        Gdx.app.debug(TAG,"WorldRenderer: virtual: ("+VIEWPORT.virtualWidth+","+VIEWPORT.virtualHeight+")");
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "WorldRenderer: viewport: (" +VIEWPORT.viewportWidth+","+VIEWPORT.viewportHeight+")");
        Gdx.app.debug(TAG,"WorldRenderer: physical: ("+VIEWPORT.physicalWidth+","+VIEWPORT.physicalHeight+")");



    }

    @Override
    public void resume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

/

```
package com.bludbourne.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;


import com.bludbourne.game.screens.MainGameScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class BludBourne extends Game {

    public static final MainGameScreen _mainGameScreen = new MainGameScreen();


    @Override
    public void create () {
        setScreen(_mainGameScreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        _mainGameScreen.dispose();
    }
}
```

/

```
package com.bludbourne.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.resolvers.InternalFileHandleResolver;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;

public final class Utility
{

    public static final AssetManager            _assetManager       = new AssetManager();

    private static final String                 TAG                 = Utility.class.getSimpleName();

    private static InternalFileHandleResolver   _filePathResolver   = new InternalFileHandleResolver();

    public static void unloadAsset(String assetFilenamePath)
    {

        if (_assetManager.isLoaded(assetFilenamePath))
        {

            _assetManager.unload(assetFilenamePath);

        }
        else
        {

            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Asset is not loaded; Nothing to unload: " + assetFilenamePath);

        }

    }

    public static float loadCompleted()
    {

        return _assetManager.getProgress();

    }

    public static int numberAssetsQueued()
    {

        return _assetManager.getQueuedAssets();

    }

    public static boolean updateAssetLoading()
    {

        return _assetManager.update();

    }

    public static boolean isAssetLoaded(String fileName)
    {

        return _assetManager.isLoaded(fileName);

    }

    public static void loadMapAsset(String mapFilenamePath)
    {

        if (mapFilenamePath == null || mapFilenamePath.isEmpty())
        {

            return;
        }

        if (_filePathResolver.resolve(mapFilenamePath).exists())
        {

            _assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(_filePathResolver));
            _assetManager.load(mapFilenamePath, TiledMap.class);
            _assetManager.finishLoadingAsset(mapFilenamePath);
            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Map loaded!: " + mapFilenamePath);

        }

        else
        {

            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Map doesn't exist!: " + mapFilenamePath);

        }

    }

    public static TiledMap getMapAsset(String mapFilenamePath)
    {

        TiledMap map = null;

        if (_assetManager.isLoaded(mapFilenamePath))
        {

            map = _assetManager.get(mapFilenamePath, TiledMap.class);

        }

        else
        {

            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Map is not loaded: " + mapFilenamePath);

        }

        return map;
    }

    public static void loadTextureAsset(String textureFilenamePath) {

        if (textureFilenamePath == null||textureFilenamePath.isEmpty()) {

            return;
        }
        if (_filePathResolver.resolve(textureFilenamePath).exists()) {

            _assetManager.setLoader(Texture.class, new TextureLoader(_filePathResolver));

            _assetManager.load(textureFilenamePath,Texture.class);

            _assetManager.finishLoadingAsset(textureFilenamePath);
        }

        else {

            Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Texture doesn't exist!: "+textureFilenamePath);

        }

    }


    public static Texture getTextureAsset(String textureFilenamePath) {

        Texture texture =null;

        if(_assetManager.isLoaded(textureFilenamePath)) {

            texture = _assetManager.get(textureFilenamePath,Texture.class);

        }

        else {

            Gdx.app.debug(TAG,"Texture is not loaded: "+textureFilenamePath);


        }



        return texture;

    }


}
```

I've included a link to my github so you can see the project structure as well. I think I have structured the project correctly, however, I don't know.

I have included

Assets/sprites/characters/Warrior.png

Assets/maps/castle_of_doom.tmx

Assets/maps/town.tmx

Assets/maps/topworld.tmx

src/com/bludbourne/game/MapManager.java

src/com/bludbourne/game/PlayerController.java

src/com/bludbourne/game/Utility.java

due to the 30k character limit.

Here is a link to my github https://github.com/davey67/bludbourne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your desktop launcher you create 2 LwjglApplication's by mistake.

```
new LwjglApplication(new BludBourne(), config); //YOU HAVE 2 OF THESE
```

Just delete the first one

```
       LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new BludBourne(), config);  <--DELETE THIS LINE
```

I would think that would fix your problems.